# JSON Data format to remove escaped characters

Tags: c#, json

Having some trouble with parsing some JSON data, and removing the escaped characters so that I can then assign the values to a List. I've read lots of pages on SO about this very thing, and where people are having success, I am just now. I was wondering if anyone could run their eyes over my method to see what I am doing wrong?

The API I have fetching the JSON data from is from IPStack. It allows me to capture location based data from website visitors.

Here is how I am building up the API path. The two querystrings i've added to the URI are the access key that APIStack give you to use, as well as fields=main which gives you the main location based data (they have a few other blocks of data you can also get).

```
        string api_URI = "http://api.ipstack.com/";
        string api_IP = "100.121.126.33";
        string api_KEY = "8378273uy12938";
        string api_PATH = string.Format("{0}{1}?access_key={2}&fields=main", api_URI, api_IP, api_KEY);
```

The rest of the code in my method to pull the JSON data in is as follows.

```
        System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
        Uri myUri = new Uri(api_PATH, UriKind.Absolute);
        var jsonResponse = wc.DownloadString(myUri);
        dynamic Data = Json.Decode(jsonResponse);
```

This gives me a JSON string that looks like this. (I have entered on each key/value to show you the format better). The IP and KEY I have obfuscated from my own details, but it won't matter in this summary anyway.

```
"{
\"ip\":\"100.121.126.33\",
\"type\":\"ipv4\",
\"continent_code\":\"OC\",
\"continent_name\":\"Oceania\",
\"country_code\":\"AU\",
\"country_name\":\"Australia\"
}"
```

This is where I believe the issue lies, in that I cannot remove the escaped characters. I have tried to use Regex.Escape(jsonResponse.ToString()); and whilst this does not throw any errors, it actually doesn't remove the \ characters either. It leaves me with the exact same string that went into it.

The rest of my method is to create a List which has one public string (country_name) just for limiting the scope during the test.

```
        List<IPLookup> List = new List<IPLookup>();

        foreach (var x in Data)
        {
            List.Add(new IPLookup()
            {
                country_name = x.country_name
            });
        }
```

The actual error in Visual Studio is thrown when it tries to add country_name to the List, as it complains that it does not contain country_name, and i'm presuming because it still has it's backslash attached to it?

Any help or pointers on where I can look to fix this one up?

Comment: Are you sure there *are* actually any backslashes in the string? Perhaps you're just seeing them in the debugger? What happens if you print the string to the console? (And what is `Json.Decode` in this case?)

Comment: Hi Jon, i'll try print the output to the console to see if that differs to what i'm seeing in VS when i can inspect it. Json.Decode is from the System.Web.Helpers namespace. the Json class has a Decode method which converts data in JSON format into the specified strongly typed data list.

Comment: As above, it might just be your debugger outputting that string, your data object might be fine.   What is the output of `Console.Writeline(Data)` and `Console.Writeline(Data.ip)`?

Comment: You guys are right! When i output Data.ip or Data.country_name etc, it works perfectly. I've been trying to solve a problem that didn't actually exist. Now I feel stupid, but also feel I've learnt something just from this. Thanks guys, appreciate the comments.

Comment: Just a note, are they actually your API keys?  If so - you might want to redact them from your question.

Comment: No, as stated in the question i have obfuscated them completely. It is complete bogus data :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved just from the questions posed by Jon and Luke which got me looking at the problem from another angle.

Rather than finish my method in a foreach statement and trying to assign via x.something,,, I simple replaced that block of code with the following.

```
List<IPLookup> List = new List<IPLookup>();
List.Add(new IPLookup()
{
    country_name = Data.country_name, 
 });
```

I can now access the key/value pairs from this JSON data without having to try remove the escaped characters that my debugger was showing me to have...